# How can write and read a java bitset from python?

Tags: java, python, bitset, jpype

I am using the chemistry development kit to calculate 'fingerprints' for chemical structures. I would like to save these in an sql database, but Im note sure what the best way to store and then read the data. I am currently using python because there are other parts of the code that wont work in jython.

I am using jpype to interface to package.

```
import os
from jpype import *

_jvm=os.environ["JPYPE_JVM"]
_cp=os.environ['CLASSPATH']
startJVM(_jvm, "-Djava.class.path="+_cp)
cdk=JPackage("org").openscience.cdk
```

The sample part that does all the work is below:

```
sp = cdk.smiles.SmilesParser(cdk.DefaultChemObjectBuilder.getInstance())
mol=sp.parseSmiles('CCCCC')    
ECFP=cdk.fingerprint.CircularFingerprinter
fingerp=ECFP(ECFP.CLASS_ECFP6)
fp1 = fingerp.getBitFingerprint(mol).asBitSet()
fp1.toString()
```

this outputs

```
out: u'{61, 152, 222, 777, 825, 947, 993}'
```

note that fp1 is a BitSet.

EDIT: I am stuck on reading a the output string into a bitset again.

What I have tried

```
fps=fp1.toString()    
bit=java.util.BitSet.valueOf({fps})
```

This returns

```
RuntimeError: No matching overloads found. at src/native/common/jp_method.cpp:121
```

Comment: What does 'efficient' mean? It doesn't look very big so in what ways do you want it to be 'efficient'?

Comment: @pvg Well this is just one example. This will likely have to be performed for over a million different files. So the read/write needs to be as fast as possible.

Comment: It needs to be as fast as possible only if you know it's taking a significant part of overall runtime. So sanest thing is, implement it naively, measure it, and if there's a problem, come back with a specific question. As it is, this is too vague to answer and any answers would be guesswork.

Comment: @pvg The part that I am stuck on is reading the output string back into a bitset. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: You need to be looking at the Javadoc for these classes. `BitSet` doesn't have a `valueOf` method that takes a string. you could use the `toLongArray` and `valueOf`, for instance, the other options should also be clear from the docs.